# Associative arrays in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an associative array like this:

```
var names = { '10watt' : '_ULR', '20watt' : '_ULR', '30watt' : '_ULR', '40watt' : '_ULR', '50watt' : '_ULR', '60watt' : '_ULR', '75watt' : '_ULR', '100watt' : 'ULCR', '120watt' : 'ULCR', '150watt' : 'ULCR' };
```

how do I write the value of the key to the browser, if the key is this.id?

I tried this but it didn't work (#name is the div I want to put the text in:

```
$('#name').text(names(this.id));
```

Comment: This isn't an associative array, it's an object.

Comment: An object is an associative array, but yeah, in JS they are called Objects and should not be confused with Array (which extends Object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#name').text(names[this.id])
```

This is not related to jQuery in any way though. 
In JavaScript, if you have an object `obj`, then you can access its property `prop` either like this `obj.prop`, or like this `obj["prop"]`.

Comment: more general form: `obj[expression]` so anything is possible e.g: `obj["prop"+(myint*(9-3+6))+mystring]`